# Docker + puppeteer + nodejs + chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, google-chrome, puppeteer

I have an error in my code, looking forward to your help!

I am writing a testing puppeteer that automatically enters the site on nodejs (the code works), but when I save it and run it in Docker it doesn't work at all (chrome can't boot).

Any help makes me happy!

We hope to receive your help !!

code js

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');
const download = require('image-downloader');
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require("express");



// buildPaths.js
const { buildPathHtml, buildPathPdf } = require('./buildPaths');
(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({        
    executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe',
    headless: false,
    slowMo:300,
    args: [
        //'--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs',
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox'
    ]
    });    
    console.log('Browser opened');
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    // dịnh dạng khung cửa sổ hiển thị
   // page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 926 });
   try{
  const pageURL =  await page.goto('http://kenh14.vn/', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 0});
    console.log('Page loaded');
    console.log(`opened the page: ${pageURL}`);
   }catch(error){
       console.log(`failed to open the page: ${pageURL} with the error: ${error}`);
   }
```

dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest
RUN  apt-get update \
     && apt-get install -y wget gnupg ca-certificates \
     && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
     && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
     && apt-get update \
     # We install Chrome to get all the OS level dependencies, but Chrome itself
     # is not actually used as it's packaged in the node puppeteer library.
     # Alternatively, we could could include the entire dep list ourselves
     # (https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#chrome-headless-doesnt-launch-on-unix)
     # but that seems too easy to get out of date.
     && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable \
     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
     && wget --quiet https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/master/wait-for-it.sh -O /usr/sbin/wait-for-it.sh \
     && chmod +x /usr/sbin/wait-for-it.sh    
RUN mkdir -p /app/src    
WORKDIR /app/src    
# COPY package.json .  
COPY  package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . . 
#EXPOSE 4001
CMD ["node","puppeteer-one-page.js"]
```

Comment: try to run without `executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe',` and `headless: false,`

Comment: Add any error you encounter please

Comment: thanks for your kind help, i'm still getting error like this " terminal will be reused by task, press any key to cloase it" and docker turns off automatically

Answer (score 1):

Inside container you cannot access host machine's files if you do not use a volume binding.

Try binding chrome folder via

`docker run -v  C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application:/opt/chrome .`

so add `-v  C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application:/opt/chrome` to your docker run.(similarly you can use docker-compose `volume` option)

Then use "/opt/chrome/chrome.exe" for `executablePath`

references

- compose reference v3: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes
- tutorial on volumes: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: thanks for your kind help, i'm still getting error like this  " terminal will be reused by task, press any key to cloase it" and docker turns off automatically